# Spring integration DSL unable to copy files with Sftp Inbound Adapter in java 1.7

Tags: spring-integration

After testing my Sftp inbound flow I found that when my local directory is empty then all files from remote directory are successfully copied to my local directory but if atleast one file is present in the local directory then none of the files getting copied from the remote directory. So can any ony one please provide any pointer to it as I am not able to fix it.

This is my Sftp inbound flow....

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory)
                    .preserveTimestamp(true).remoteDirectory(remDir)
                    .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")
                    .localFilenameExpression("#this.toUpperCase()")
                    .localDirectory(new File(localDir))
                    .remoteFileSeparator("/"),
                    new Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(
                                SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec e) {
                            e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
                                    .autoStartup(true)
                                    .poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000)
                                            .maxMessagesPerPoll(1));
                        }
                    })
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("sftpInboundResultChannel"))
            .get();
}
```

And this is my Test method..

```
@Test
public void testSftpInboundFlow() {

    Message<?> message = ((PollableChannel) sftpInboundResultChannel).receive(60000);
    System.out.println("message====" + message);        
}
```

Please find the log for the same ...........

```
INFO: Authentication succeeded (password).
enter sftpSessionFactory.....org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@10cea2e
enter sftpInboundFlow.....org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@17ebea9
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start
INFO: Starting beans in phase -2147483648
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start
INFO: Starting beans in phase 0
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer logComponentSubscriptionEvent
INFO: Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel adjustCounterIfNecessary
INFO: Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@13fb256.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer start
INFO: started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start
INFO: Starting beans in phase 1073741823
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter start
INFO: started sftpInboundAdapter
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource receive
INFO: Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=D:\local_copy\Test_sftp.txt, headers={timestamp=1437052401259, id=7e6054ea-9fbc-e9f0-b3e2-9c5dede1556a}]]
the channel is sftpInboundResultChannel
the sftpInboundAdapter is org.springframework.integration.dsl.sftp.SftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec@8df4ff
message====GenericMessage [payload=D:\local_copy\Test_sftp.txt, headers={timestamp=1437052401259, id=7e6054ea-9fbc-e9f0-b3e2-9c5dede1556a}]
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@13fb256: startup date [Thu Jul 16 18:43:10 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor stop
INFO: Stopping beans in phase 1073741823
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter stop
INFO: stopped sftpInboundAdapter
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor stop
INFO: Stopping beans in phase 0
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer logComponentSubscriptionEvent
INFO: Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel adjustCounterIfNecessary
INFO: Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@13fb256.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer stop
INFO: stopped _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor stop
INFO: Stopping beans in phase -2147483648
Jul 16, 2015 6:43:21 PM org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler shutdown
INFO: Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
```

Comment: Please, answer to these questions: 1. Are you facing an issue during the same testing iteration or have you stopped your app before the second test? 2. Is that existing file one of those from SFTP? 4. Share DEBUG logs for the `org.springframework.integration` for tat wrong case.

Comment: Hi Artem, I have created a separate class for Sftp ibound adapter. When ever I am running this through Junit the same issue is coming. No matter about the file as the same problem occurs in the existing file of SFTP as well as any new file. I have shared the log in my original post.

Comment: Seems for you you again have an issue with context `close()`. See your logs: `message====GenericMessage` and just after that you go out from the `@Junit` test. Really your issue does not make sense...